# Creating framework for Cocoapods from Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package with the following structure:

[image]

I need to generate a framework for distribution via Cocoapods as well. Below is what I used to generate this when it was previously an Xcode framework project - how do I generate a framework for Cocoapods if I'm building directly from a Swift package?

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -scheme roboflow-swift \
    -archivePath "archives/roboflow-swift-iOS.xcarchive" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive \
    -scheme roboflow-swift \
    -archivePath "archives/roboflow-swift-iOS-simulator.xcarchive" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "archives/roboflow-swift-iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/roboflow-swift.framework" \
    -framework "archives/roboflow-swift-iOS-simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/roboflow-swift.framework" \
    -output "roboflow-swift.xcframework"
```